# Oracle SQL : Check if specified words are present in comma separated string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have an SQL function that returns me a string of comma separated country codes.

I have configured some specific codes in another table and I may remove or add more later.

I want to check if the comma separated string is only the combination of those specific country codes or not. That said, if that string is having even a single country code other than the specified ones, it should return true.

Suppose I configured two rows in the static data table GB and CH. Then I need below results:

| String from function | result |
| --- | --- |
| GB | false |
| CH | false |
| GB,CH | false |
| CH,GB | false |
| GB,FR | true |
| FR,ES | true |
| ES,CH | true |
| CH,GB,ES | true |

I am on Oracle 19c and can use only the functions available for this version. Plus I want it to be optimised. Like I can check the number of values in string and then count for each specific code. If not matching then obviously some other codes are present. But I don't want to use loops.

Can someone please suggest me a better option.

Comment: why not modify yor function to count the single values, imstead you have to make them to rows again. Bad idea

Comment: @nbk I'm using an existing function so I can not modify it. I cannot rewrite the entire function for my usage.

Comment: In the comma-separated string, will you always have two-letter country codes **exclusively**? If so, you could take advantage of that: you would not need to worry about an input "country code" such as GBCH (a **single** country code) that could be confused for GB and CH (in some efficient solutions). So - more info about the inputs please! Are all country codes exactly two letters? Are all tokens in the string also exactly two-letter tokens?

Comment: @mathguy Yes it is certain that there are only 2 characters in the country code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all country codes in the static table, as well as all tokens in the comma-separated strings, are always exactly two-letter strings, you could do something like this:

```
with
  static_data(country_code) as (
    select 'GB' from dual union all
    select 'CH' from dual
  )
, sample_inputs(string_from_function) as (
    select 'GB'       from dual union all
    select 'CH'       from dual union all
    select 'GB,CH'    from dual union all
    select 'CH,GB'    from dual union all
    select 'GB,FR'    from dual union all
    select 'FR,ES'    from dual union all
    select 'ES,CH'    from dual union all
    select 'CH,GB,ES' from dual
  )
select string_from_function,
       case when regexp_replace(string_from_function,
                   ',| |' || (select listagg(country_code, '|')
                                       within group (order by null)
                              from   static_data))
                 is null then 'false' else 'true' end as result
from   sample_inputs
;
```

Output:

```
STRING_FROM_FUNCTION   RESULT  
---------------------- --------
GB                     false   
CH                     false   
GB,CH                  false   
CH,GB                  false   
GB,FR                  true    
FR,ES                  true    
ES,CH                  true    
CH,GB,ES               true
```

The regular expression replaces comma, space, and every two-letter country code from the static data table with `null`. If the result of the whole thing is `null`, then all coded in the csv are in the static table; that's what you need to test for.

The assumptions guarantee that a token like GBCH (for a country like "Great Barrier Country Heat") would not be mistakenly considered OK because GB and CH are OK separately.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy. This solution is better and best suited for my requirement. Here is what I am gonna do: Replaced the static data from multiple rows to single row (GB|CH) to remove the listagg() function call. Then rest is same as your solution. It will even handle corner cases (null and '').

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a csv column to a table and use EXISTS. For example

```
with tbl(id,str) as
( 
SELECT 1,'GB,CH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'GB,CH,FR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'GB' FROM DUAL 
),
countries (code) as
(SELECT 'GB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'CH' FROM DUAL 
)

select t.* ,
     case when exists (
        select 1 
        from xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(str, ',', '","') || '"')) s  
        where trim(s.column_value) not in (select code from countries)
      ) 
      then 'true' else 'false' end flag
from tbl t
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to match the country codes one by one, and then determine whether there exists an extra non-matched country from the provided literal as parameter.

The following one with FULL JOIN would help by considering the logic above

```sql
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(i_countries VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    o_val VARCHAR2(10);
  BEGIN
     SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(NVL2(t.country_code,0,1))=0 THEN 'false' 
                 ELSE 'true'
                  END
       INTO o_val           
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(i_countries,'[^ ,]+',1,level) AS country
               FROM dual
            CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(i_countries,',')+1) tt
       FULL JOIN t
              ON tt.country = t.country_code;      
    RETURN o_val;
  END;
SELECT with_function(<comma-seperated-parameter-list>) AS result
  FROM dual
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a3c7cef59ea7a6d8fe31e15ec8dfa301)</kbd>

Comment: Can you please explain in brief how this works. Also I don't think full join is available in Oracle 19c sql developer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: that's a classical hierarchical query in order to split the comma seperated strings by comma and to generate rows similar to your table's structure. Then determine if there's more or less countries exist within your parameter than the counterparts stored in the table by outer joining them. The `FULL JOIN` clause exists from the ancient versions of the Oracle DB @TalkChatAdmin. so it even exists within the DB version 19c. Best wishes.

Comment: I got your point. Even if we use minus (set difference), it will work right @Barbaros ?

Comment: @TalkChatAdmin sure you can

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

> ```
> with cte as
> (select distinct
> s,regexp_substr(s, '[^,]+',1, level) code from strings
>     
>  connect by regexp_substr(s, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
> )
> select 
> s string,min(case when exists
>   (select * from countries
>    where cod = code) then 'yes'
>    else 'no'end) all_found
> from cte
> group by s
> order by s;
> ```

> ```
> STRING | ALL_FOUND
> :----- | :--------
> CH     | yes      
> CH,GB  | yes      
> ES     | no       
> ES,CH  | no       
> FR     | no       
> GB     | yes      
> GB,CH  | yes      
> GB,ES  | no
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=046f6e6dcebba1f055064f88df3f670d)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of values in the static table then the simplest method may not be to split the values from the function but to generate all combinations of values from the static table using:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(value, ','), 2) AS combination
FROM   static_table
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR value != value;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE static_table(value) AS
SELECT 'GB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CH' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COMBINATION |
> | --- |
> | GB |
> | GB,CH |
> | CH |
> | CH,GB |

Then you can use a simple `CASE` expression to your string output to the combinations:

```sql
SELECT function_value,
       CASE
       WHEN function_value IN (SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(value, ','), 2)
                               FROM   static_table
                               CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR value != value)
       THEN 'false'
       ELSE 'true'
       END AS not_matched
FROM   string_from_function;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE string_from_function(function_value) AS
SELECT 'GB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GB,CH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CH,GB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GB,FR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FR,ES' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ES,CH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CH,GB,ES' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FUNCTION_VALUE | NOT_MATCHED |
> | --- | --- |
> | GB | false |
> | CH | false |
> | GB,CH | false |
> | CH,GB | false |
> | GB,FR | true |
> | FR,ES | true |
> | ES,CH | true |
> | CH,GB,ES | true |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=830dcbb54ad3fcac87f6da87e4fd09e9)*

Comment: Right but in future there can be more country codes added.